# Foliations, von Neumann algebras and measurability

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, von-neumann-algebras, foliations, holonomy

In the excellent book *Noncommutative Geometry* by Alain Connes much of the first chapter is devoted to foliations. At the end of the first chapter the author discusses index theory on *measured* foliations (foliation equipped with the so called *transverse measure*). From the discussion there I didin't get how this assumption is restrictive: I would guess that this should somehow be related to being type II (for the von Neumann algebra of the foliation).

There is also the assumption that every leaf of the foliation has trivial holonomy: why do we need this assumption and how much is it restrictive?

I would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on those issues.